# Pandas timeseries plot setting x-axis major and minor ticks and labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series, xticks

I want to be able to set the major and minor xticks and their labels for a time series graph plotted from a Pandas time series object.

The Pandas 0.9 "what's new" page says:

> "you can either use to_pydatetime or register a converter for the
> Timestamp type"

but I can't work out how to do that so that I can use the matplotlib `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator` and `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter` (and minor) commands.

If I use them without converting the pandas times, the x-axis ticks and labels end up wrong.

By using the 'xticks' parameter, I can pass the major ticks to pandas' `.plot`, and then set the major tick labels. I can't work out how to do the minor ticks using this approach (I can set the labels on the default minor ticks set by pandas' `.plot`).

Here is my test code:

###### Graph with strange dates on xaxis

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np

dateIndex = pd.date_range(start='2011-05-01', end='2011-07-01', freq='D')
testSeries = pd.Series(data=np.random.randn(len(dateIndex)), index=dateIndex)    

ax = plt.figure(figsize=(7,4), dpi=300).add_subplot(111)
testSeries.plot(ax=ax, style='v-', label='first line')    

# using MatPlotLib date time locators and formatters doesn't work with new
# pandas datetime index
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.WeekdayLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d\n%a'))
ax.xaxis.grid(True, which="minor")
ax.xaxis.grid(False, which="major")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('\n\n\n%b%Y'))
plt.show()
```

[image: Graph with strange dates on xaxis]

###### Graph with correct dates (without minor ticks)

```py
# set the major xticks and labels through pandas
ax2 = plt.figure(figsize=(7,4), dpi=300).add_subplot(111)
xticks = pd.date_range(start='2011-05-01', end='2011-07-01', freq='W-Tue')
testSeries.plot(ax=ax2, style='-v', label='second line', xticks=xticks.to_pydatetime())
ax2.set_xticklabels([x.strftime('%a\n%d\n%h\n%Y') for x in xticks]);
# remove the minor xtick labels set by pandas.plot 
ax2.set_xticklabels([], minor=True)
# turn the minor ticks created by pandas.plot off 
plt.show()
```

[image: Graph with correct dates]

**Update:** I've been able to get closer to the layout I wanted by using a loop to build the major xtick labels:

```py
# only show month for first label in month
month = dStart.month - 1
xticklabels = []
for x in xticks:
    if  month != x.month :
        xticklabels.append(x.strftime('%d\n%a\n%h'))
        month = x.month
    else:
        xticklabels.append(x.strftime('%d\n%a'))
```

However, this is a bit like doing the x-axis using `ax.annotate`: possible but not ideal.

How do I set the major and minor ticks when plotting pandas time-series data?

Comment: I know this doesn't really answer the question, but as a general approach when I really care about how a plot looks, I generally just try to get a vector version of it and make it look nice in Illustrator or Inkscape. I've found most other people I know seem to do the same.

Comment: Can you just totally ignore the arguments to the pandas `plot` function and set all the ticks after plotting, by using matplotlib methods of the returned `ax` object (e.g., `ax.set_xticks`)?

Comment: @BrenBarn I couldn't figure out how to get the date as a python date instead of a pandas datetime for the matplotlib methods. The answer by bmu fixes that by converting the dates before plotting.

Comment: You can actually plot with pandas and still use matplotlib.dates without any date conversion needed, thanks to this argument: `testSeries.plot(x_compat=True)`. This was [added to pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.9.1.html) just a few weeks after you posted this question.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Both `pandas` and `matplotlib.dates` use `matplotlib.units` for locating the ticks.

But while `matplotlib.dates` has convenient ways to set the ticks manually, pandas seems to have the focus on auto formatting so far (you can have a look at the [code](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/tseries/converter.py) for date conversion and formatting in pandas).

So for the moment it seems more reasonable to use `matplotlib.dates` (as mentioned by @BrenBarn in his comment).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.dates as dates

idx = pd.date_range('2011-05-01', '2011-07-01')
s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(idx)), index=idx)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot_date(idx.to_pydatetime(), s, 'v-')
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(dates.WeekdayLocator(byweekday=(1),
                                                interval=1))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%d\n%a'))
ax.xaxis.grid(True, which="minor")
ax.yaxis.grid()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.MonthLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('\n\n\n%b\n%Y'))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: pandas_like_date_fomatting]

(my locale is German, so that Tuesday [Tue] becomes Dienstag [Di])

Answer (score 3):

To turn off Pandas Datetime tick adjustment, you have to add the argument `x_compat=True`

Example:

```py
ds.plot(x_compat=True)
```

See more examples in the Pandas documentation: [Suppressing tick resolution adjustment](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html#suppressing-tick-resolution-adjustment)

Comment: nice hint, hard to find in the docs (at least that for df.plot)!

Answer (score 1):

In matplotlib's `plot()`, the default time-series unit is 1 day but in pandas' `plot()`, 1 unit is equal to the frequency of the time-series, so if the frequency is 1 day, 1 unit is 1 day; if it is 1 hour, then it is 1 hour etc. This makes the `plot()` calls of matplotlib and pandas different when it comes to time-series data.

If **the frequency of the time-series is 1-day**, then `matplotlib.dates.WeekdayLocator`, `matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator` etc. can "locate" tick positions<sup>1</sup> because 1 day is used as the base unit to make xtick positions by pandas `plot()` (coincides with matplotlib's default).

Since pandas' `plot()` call returns an Axes object, the tick labels of that Axes object may be modified using `matplotlib.dates`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

idx = pd.date_range('2011-05-01', '2011-07-01', freq='D')
s1 = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(idx)), index=idx)

ax = s1.plot(style='v-')
ax.xaxis.set(
    minor_locator=mdates.WeekdayLocator(),               # make minor ticks on each Tuesday
    minor_formatter=mdates.DateFormatter('%d\n%a'),      # format minor ticks
    major_locator=mdates.MonthLocator(),                 # make major ticks on first day of each month
    major_formatter=mdates.DateFormatter('\n\n\n%b\n%Y') # format major ticks
);
```

[image: first image]

---

However, if the frequency is not 1-day but, say, 1-week, then `matplotlib.dates` won't be able to locate the positions because, as mentioned previously, pandas' `plot()` sets the unit to be the same as the time-series frequency (1-week), which "confuses" `matplotlib.dates`. So if we try to use the same code used to set tick labels of `s1` to set the tick labels of `s2`, then we would get very wrong ticklabels.

To "solve" the problem, one way is to remove pandas' automatic tick resolution adjustment by passing `x_compat=True`. Then major/minor tick labels may be set using matplotlib's resolution; in other words, it may be set in the same way as above.

```py
idx = pd.date_range('2011-05-01', '2011-07-01', freq='W')
s2 = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(idx)), index=idx)

ax = s2.plot(style='v-', x_compat=True, rot=0)
ax.xaxis.set(
    minor_locator=mdates.WeekdayLocator(),              # make minor ticks on each Tuesday
    minor_formatter=mdates.DateFormatter('%d'),         # format minor ticks
    major_locator=mdates.MonthLocator(),                # make major ticks on first day of each month
    major_formatter=mdates.DateFormatter('\n\n%b\n%Y')  # format major ticks
);
```

[image: second image]

Another way to get around the issue is to use matplotlib's `plot()` instead (as suggested by [@bmu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13674286/19123103)). Because the unit is fixed in matplotlib, we can set the tick labels as above without issue.

```py
plt.plot(s2.index, s2, 'v-')                            # use matplotlib instead
plt.gca().xaxis.set(
    minor_locator=mdates.WeekdayLocator(byweekday=0),   # make minor ticks on each Monday
    minor_formatter=mdates.DateFormatter('%d'),         # format minor ticks
    major_locator=mdates.MonthLocator(),                # make major ticks on first day of each month
    major_formatter=mdates.DateFormatter('\n\n%b\n%Y')  # format major ticks
);
```

---

<sup>1</sup> `matplotlib.dates.num2timedelta(1) == datetime.timedelta(days=1)` is True.