# pandas day of week axis labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I am plotting a pandas series that spans one week.  My code:

```
rng = pd.date_range('1/6/2014',periods=169,freq='H')
graph = pd.Series(shared_index, index=rng[:168])
graph.plot(shared_index)
```

Which displays 7 x-axis labels:

```
[06 Jan 2014, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12]
```

But I want:

```
[Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun]
```

What do I specify in code to change axis labels?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

perhaps you can manually fix the tick labels:

```
rng = pd.date_range('1/6/2014',periods=169,freq='H')
graph = pd.Series(np.random.randn(168), index=rng[:168])
ax = graph.plot()

weekday_map= {0:'MON', 1:'TUE', 2:'WED', 3:'THU',
              4:'FRI', 5:'SAT', 6:'SUN'}

xs = sorted(ax.get_xticks(minor='both'))
wd = graph.index[xs - xs[0]].map(pd.Timestamp.weekday)

ax.set_xticks(xs)
ax.set_xticks([], minor=True)
ax.set_xticklabels([weekday_map[d] for d in wd])
```

[image: week-day]

Comment: It would be great if there were a solution that used `matplotlib.dates.WeekdayLocator` somehow

Comment: @PrageethJayathissa what about this one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13674286/15485