# Pandas: Group by calendar-week, then plot grouped barplots for the real datetime

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, calendar, group-by

### EDIT

I found a quite nice solution and posted it below as an answer.
The result will look like this:

[image]

---

Some example data you can generate for this problem:

```
codes = list('ABCDEFGH'); 
dates = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2013-11-01', '2014-01-31')); 
dates = dates.append(dates)
dates.sort()
df = pd.DataFrame({'amount': np.random.randint(1, 10, dates.size), 'col1': np.random.choice(codes, dates.size), 'col2': np.random.choice(codes, dates.size), 'date': dates})
```

resulting in:

```
In [55]: df
Out[55]:
    amount col1 col2       date
0        1    D    E 2013-11-01
0        5    E    B 2013-11-01
1        5    G    A 2013-11-02
1        7    D    H 2013-11-02
2        5    E    G 2013-11-03
2        4    H    G 2013-11-03
3        7    A    F 2013-11-04
3        3    A    A 2013-11-04
4        1    E    G 2013-11-05
4        7    D    C 2013-11-05
5        5    C    A 2013-11-06
5        7    H    F 2013-11-06
6        1    G    B 2013-11-07
6        8    D    A 2013-11-07
7        1    B    H 2013-11-08
7        8    F    H 2013-11-08
8        3    A    E 2013-11-09
8        1    H    D 2013-11-09
9        3    B    D 2013-11-10
9        1    H    G 2013-11-10
10       6    E    E 2013-11-11
10       6    F    E 2013-11-11
11       2    G    B 2013-11-12
11       5    H    H 2013-11-12
12       5    F    G 2013-11-13
12       5    G    B 2013-11-13
13       8    H    B 2013-11-14
13       6    G    F 2013-11-14
14       9    F    C 2013-11-15
14       4    H    A 2013-11-15
..     ...  ...  ...        ...
77       9    A    B 2014-01-17
77       7    E    B 2014-01-17
78       4    F    E 2014-01-18
78       6    B    E 2014-01-18
79       6    A    H 2014-01-19
79       3    G    D 2014-01-19
80       7    E    E 2014-01-20
80       6    G    C 2014-01-20
81       9    H    G 2014-01-21
81       9    C    B 2014-01-21
82       2    D    D 2014-01-22
82       7    D    A 2014-01-22
83       6    G    B 2014-01-23
83       1    A    G 2014-01-23
84       9    B    D 2014-01-24
84       7    G    D 2014-01-24
85       7    A    F 2014-01-25
85       9    B    H 2014-01-25
86       9    C    D 2014-01-26
86       5    E    B 2014-01-26
87       3    C    H 2014-01-27
87       7    F    D 2014-01-27
88       3    D    G 2014-01-28
88       4    A    D 2014-01-28
89       2    F    A 2014-01-29
89       8    D    A 2014-01-29
90       1    A    G 2014-01-30
90       6    C    A 2014-01-30
91       6    H    C 2014-01-31
91       2    G    F 2014-01-31

[184 rows x 4 columns]
```

I'd like to group by calendar-week and by value of `col1`. Like this:

```
kw = lambda x: x.isocalendar()[1]
grouped = df.groupby([df['date'].map(kw), 'col1'], sort=False).agg({'amount': 'sum'})
```

resulting in:

```
In [58]: grouped
Out[58]:
           amount
date col1
44   D          8
     E         10
     G          5
     H          4
45   D         15
     E          1
     G          1
     H          9
     A         13
     C          5
     B          4
     F          8
46   E          7
     G         13
     H         17
     B          9
     F         23
47   G         14
     H          4
     A         40
     C          7
     B         16
     F         13
48   D          7
     E         16
     G          9
     H          2
     A          7
     C          7
     B          2
...           ...
1    H         14
     A         14
     B         15
     F         19
2    D         13
     H         13
     A         13
     B         10
     F         32
3    D          8
     E         18
     G          3
     H          6
     A         30
     C          9
     B          6
     F          5
4    D          9
     E         12
     G         19
     H          9
     A          8
     C         18
     B         18
5    D         11
     G          2
     H          6
     A          5
     C          9
     F          9

[87 rows x 1 columns]
```

Then I want a plot to be generated like this:
[image]
That means: calendar-week and year (datetime) on the x-axis and for each of the grouped `col1` one bar.

The problem I'm facing is: I only have integers describing the calendar week (KW in the plot), but I somehow have to merge back the date on it to get the ticks labeled by year as well. Furthermore I can't only plot the grouped calendar week because I need a correct order of the items (kw 47, kw 48 (year 2013) have to be on the left side of kw 1 (because this is 2014)).

---

### EDIT

I figured out from here:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#visualization-barplot that grouped bars need to be columns instead of rows. So I thought about how to transform the data and found the method `pivot` which turns out to be a great function. `reset_index` is needed to transform the multiindex into columns. At the end I fill `NaN`s by zero:

```
A = grouped.reset_index().pivot(index='date', columns='col1', values='amount').fillna(0)
```

transforms the data into:

```
col1   A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H
date
1      4  31   0   0   0  18  13   8
2      0  12  13  22   1  17   0   8
3      3  10   4  13  12   8   7   6
4     17   0  10   7   0  25   7   4
5      7   0   7   9   8   6   0   7
44     0   0   2  11   7   0   0   2
45     9   3   2  14   0  16  21   2
46     0  14   7   2  17  13  11   8
47     5  13   0  15  19   7   5  10
48    15   8  12   2  20   4   7   6
49    20   0   0  18  22  17  11   0
50     7  11   8   6   5   6  13  10
51     8  26   0   0   5   5  16   9
52     8  13   7   5   4  10   0  11
```

which looks like the example data in the docs to be plotted in grouped bars:

```
A. plot(kind='bar')
```

gets this:

[image]

whereas I have the problem with the axis as it is now sorted (from 1-52), which is actually wrong, because calendar week 52 belongs to year 2013 in this case... Any ideas on how to merge back the real datetime for the calendar-weeks and use them as x-axis ticks?

Comment: Comments should really go in comments. I know it's easy to get discouraged when not enough people answer the question, but the best thing to do then is *remove* non relevant parts from the question and to try and keep the question as quick-to-the-point as possible.

Comment: That wasn't a comment, really. Just a information for users which was very helpful for all readers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I answer the question myself as I finally figured it out. The key is to not group by calendar week (as you would loose information about the year) but rather group by a string containing calendar week and year.

Then change the layout (reshaping) as mentioned in the question already by using `pivot`. The date will be the index. Use `reset_index()` to make the current `date`-index a column and instead get a integer-range as an index (which is then in the correct order to be plotted (lowest-year/calendar week is index 0 and highest year/calendar week is the highest integer).

Select the `date`-column as a new variable `ticks` as a list and delete that column from the DataFrame. Now plot the bars and simply set the labels of the xticks to `ticks`. Completey solution is quite easy and here:

```
codes = list('ABCDEFGH'); 
dates = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2013-11-01', '2014-01-31')); 
dates = dates.append(dates)
dates.sort()
df = pd.DataFrame({'amount': np.random.randint(1, 10, dates.size), 'col1': np.random.choice(codes, dates.size), 'col2': np.random.choice(codes, dates.size), 'date': dates})

kw = lambda x: x.isocalendar()[1]; 
kw_year = lambda x: str(x.year) + ' - ' + str(x.isocalendar()[1])
grouped = df.groupby([df['date'].map(kw_year), 'col1'], sort=False, as_index=False).agg({'amount': 'sum'})
A = grouped.pivot(index='date', columns='col1', values='amount').fillna(0).reset_index()

ticks = A.date.values.tolist()
del A['date']
ax = A.plot(kind='bar')
ax.set_xticklabels(ticks)
```

**RESULT:**

[image]

Comment: Wow, very nice, easy and clean solution. I like it. Not much hassle about matplotlib-axisticks :)

Answer (score 9):

I think [resample('W')](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) is a better way to do this - by default it groups by weeks ending on Sunday ('W' is the same as 'W-SUN') but you can specify whatever you want.

In your example, try this:

```
grouped = (df
    .groupby('col1')                
    .apply(lambda g:               # work on groups of col1
        g.set_index('date')        
        [['amount']]
        .resample('W').agg('sum')  # sum the amount field across weeks
    )
    .unstack(level=0)              # pivot the col1 index rows to columns
    .fillna(0)
)
grouped.columns=grouped.columns.droplevel()   # drop the 'col1' part of the multi-index column names
print grouped
grouped.plot(kind='bar')
```

which should print your data table and make a plot similar to yours, but with "real" date labels:

```
col1         A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H
date                                      
2013-11-03  18  0   9   0   8   0   0   4 
2013-11-10  4   11  0   1   16  2   15  2 
2013-11-17  10  14  19  8   13  6   9   8 
2013-11-24  10  13  13  0   0   13  15  10
2013-12-01  6   3   19  8   8   17  8   12
2013-12-08  5   15  5   7   12  0   11  8 
2013-12-15  8   6   11  11  0   16  6   14
2013-12-22  16  3   13  8   8   11  15  0 
2013-12-29  1   3   6   10  7   7   17  15
2014-01-05  12  7   10  11  6   0   1   12
2014-01-12  13  0   17  0   23  0   10  12
2014-01-19  10  9   2   3   8   1   18  3 
2014-01-26  24  9   8   1   19  10  0   3 
2014-02-02  1   6   16  0   0   10  8   13
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the week to 52 times the year, so that weeks are ordered "by year". Set the tick *labels* back, [which might be nontrivial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945971/pandas-timeseries-plot-setting-x-axis-major-and-minor-ticks-and-labels), to what you want.

---

What you want is for the weeks to increase like so

```
nth week → (n+1)th week → (n+2)th week → etc.
```

but when you have a new year it instead *falls* by 51 (`52 → 1`).

To offset this, note that the year increases by one. So add the year's increase multiplied by 52 and the total change will be `-51 + 52 = 1` as wanted.

Comment: What do you mean by "Add the week to 52 times the year"? When I group by the calendar-week, the datetimes are lost, which I'd need for my plotting :(

Comment: aka. Don't group by week, group by `week + 52*year`. Although be careful about that 365th day...

Comment: Somehow I still dont get it. But maybe I jsut have to rethink about it for a while about why to add a multiple of 52 of the year to group by the returned value

Comment: Ah now I see, you meant the delta_year*52, to have the real number of weeks since the start.

Comment: Yes. Only it doesn't really matter if the years start on 2013 or so as it will just make the numbers larger (not the differences between them).