# How to choose set bin size mysql tismestamp by week in matplotlib histogram?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want make comparative study between two thing, by drawing this simultaneously, since second product launch after first product, the binning is gain difficulty to plot, I want to compare apple to apple (in same timeframe), I assume biweekly will be the best.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(1)
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('sales')
plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(111)
plt.hist((subs['pay_at'].dropna().values), bins=63)
plt.subplot(111)
plt.hist((subs['last_pay'].dropna().values), bins=10)
plt.show()
```

Here's the result

[image]

How to make one bin is two weeks in length?

Comment: You can group the data. The best way I can think is with pandas, see the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27802006/2237916

Comment: I just see this coment, this is helpful