# Skip gcf().autofmt_xdate() at pandas plot creation

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pandas

I'm trying to plot multiple time series using a pandas dataframe. The dataframe contains more than 100 registers.

From the panda's documentation I've read that when pandas.df.plot() is executed this is also executed with gcf().autofmt_xdate(). I want to put my custom datetime format but when I tried my custom date format is overlapped over the date given by default by pandas plot. ¿Is there a way to skip gcf().autofmt_xdate() on plot creation? ¿How can i provide to panda a custom datetime format?

Here is the generated plot.

[image]

Here is the python code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series
import pickle
datos = pickle.load(open("datos_reporte.pickle", "r"))
reload(plt)
series_o = []
series_p_h = []
series_p_d = []
series_names = []
for cod_estacion in datos.keys():
    x = [d[0] for d in datos[cod_estacion]['historial_semanal']]
    y = [d[1] for d in datos[cod_estacion]['historial_semanal']]
    s = Series(y, x)
    series_o.append(s.groupby(level=0).first())

df1 = pd.concat(series_o, join='outer', axis=1)
interval  = int(len(df1) / 12)
df1.columns = series_names
ax = plt.figure(figsize=(7,5), dpi=100).add_subplot(111)
df1.plot(ax=ax)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(interval=200))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m/%d-%H:%S'))
ax.xaxis.grid(True, which="minor")
plt.title("Datos observados")
plt.ylabel('Caudal m^3/s')
plt.xlabel('Fecha')
plt.legend(loc=0,prop={'size': 7})
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical', fontsize = 8)
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=.2)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can just clear all the ticks before you make new ones:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.random(20), 'B':np.random.random(20)})
df.index=pd.date_range('1/1/2014', periods=20, freq='5H')
ax = plt.figure(figsize=(7,5), dpi=100).add_subplot(111)
df.plot(ax=ax)
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_xticks([], minor=True)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(interval=200))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m/%d-%H:%S'))
ax.xaxis.grid(True, which="minor")
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical', fontsize = 8)
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=.2)
```

[image]

## Edit

Now the labels are off. `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%y/%m/%d-%H:%S'))` will show they are 1991/01/11 and so on.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.random(20), 'B':np.random.random(20)})
df.index=pd.date_range('1/1/2014', periods=20, freq='5H')
ax = plt.figure(figsize=(7,5), dpi=100).add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(df.index.to_pydatetime(), df.A, label='A')
ax.plot(df.index.to_pydatetime(), df.B, label='B')
ax.legend()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(interval=5))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%y/%m/%d-%H:%S'))
ax.xaxis.grid(True, which="major")
ax.yaxis.grid(True, which="major")
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical', fontsize = 8)
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=.2)
```

[image]

Comment: That's a good solution for overlapping issue, but do you know why the dates are altered?, you have generated dates from 01-01 to 01-04, in the chart the dates are from 01/11 to 04/12 ?, The same problem is happening to me. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Didn't notice that. It turns out the pandas timeseries is different form python datetime. This issue was (sort of) discussed before, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945971/pandas-timeseries-plot-setting-x-axis-major-and-minor-ticks-and-labels. See edit.

Comment: as as side note, you don't need `set_xticks([])`, setting a formatter will take care of everything.