# Increasing Frequency of x-axis labels for dates on DataFrame plot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot, axis-labels

I have a pandas DataFrame with two columns: `month_of_sale` which is a date, and `number_of_gizmos_sold` which is a number.

I'm trying to increase the frequency of the labels on the x-axis so it's easier to read, but I can't!

Here is the `df.head()` of my table:

[image: DataFrame.head()]

and this is what it plots:
`df.plot(y='number_of_gizmos_sold', figsize=(15,5))`

[image: DataFrame.plot()]

I'd like to increase the frequency of the labels, because there's a big space in between them.

### What I've tried

`plot.xaxis.set_major_locator(MonthLocator())` but that seems to increase the distance between the labels even more.

[image]

`plot.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))`

Strangely, I end up with this:
[image]

The questions that last plot raises for me are:

- What's up with 0002 as the year?
- And why do I still have the old `Jul` labels there too?

Comment: Give `plt.xticks(np.arange(0,len(df),5))` a shot?

Comment: @bernie, that changes the x-axis range but doesn't adjust the frequency of the ticks or labels

Comment: Ah ok. I think it works differently in pandas then. My bad.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I haven't traced the problem back to its source, but per [bmu's
solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13674286/190597), if you call `ax.plot`
instead of `df.plot`, then you can configure the result using
`ax.xaxis.set_major_locator` and `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
np.random.seed(2016)

dates = pd.date_range('2013-03-01', '2016-02-01', freq='M')
nums = (np.random.random(len(dates))-0.5).cumsum()
df = pd.DataFrame({'months': dates, 'gizmos': nums})
df['months'] = pd.to_datetime(df['months'])
df = df.set_index('months')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.index, df['gizmos'])
# df.plot(y='gizmos', ax=ax)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=2))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You're totally right, somehow Pandas is ignoring (or misusing) those parameters. If I use 
`fig, ax = plt.subplots();
ax.plot(df.index, df['gizmos'])` then it works!