# Pandas X_axis hourly

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have this little Pandascode:

```
graph = auswahl[['Volumenstrom_Außen', 'Vpunkt_Gesamt','Zuluft_Druck_10','Abluft_Druck_10']]
a = graph.plot(figsize=[50,10])
a.set(ylabel="m³/h", xlabel="Zeit", title="Volumenströme")#,ylim=[0,100])
a.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.show()
```

How can I set the X-Axis showing every Hour?

the dataframe looks like this:

```
    Volumenstrom_Außen  Vpunkt_Gesamt   Zuluft_Druck    Abluft_Druck
Zeit                
2018-02-15 16:49:00     1021.708443     752.699     49.328  46.811
2018-02-15 16:49:15     1021.708443     752.699     49.328  46.811
2018-02-15 16:49:30     1021.708443     752.699     49.328  46.811
2018-02-15 16:49:45     1021.708443     752.699     49.328  46.811
2018-02-15 16:50:00     1021.708443     752.699     49.328  46.811
2018-02-15 16:50:15     1021.708443     752.699     49.328  46.811
2018-02-15 16:50:30     1021.708443     752.699     49.328  46.811
2018-02-15 16:50:45     1021.708443     752.699     49.328  46.811
2018-02-15 16:51:00     1092.171094     752.699     49.328  46.811
2018-02-15 16:51:15     1092.171094     752.699     49.328  46.811
```

Comment: missing some code? how are you calling plot on a list of list. What is auswahl

Comment: auswahl is a DataFrame, looks like this:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take this example dataframe, whose index is at minute granularity

```
import pandas as pd
import random
ts_index = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000, freq='T')
v1 = [random.random() for i in range(1000)]
v2 = [random.random() for i in range(1000)]
v3 = [random.random() for i in range(1000)]
ts_df = pd.DataFrame({'v1':v1,'v2':v2,'v3':v3},index=ts_index)
ts_df.head()



                         v1           v2        v3
2000-01-01 00:00:00     0.593039    0.017351    0.742111
2000-01-01 00:01:00     0.563233    0.837362    0.869767
2000-01-01 00:02:00     0.453925    0.962600    0.690868
2000-01-01 00:03:00     0.757895    0.123610    0.622777
2000-01-01 00:04:00     0.759841    0.906674    0.263902
```

We could use [`pandas.DataFrame.resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html#pandas-dataframe-resample) to downsample this data to hourly granularity, like shown below

```
hourly_mean_df = ts_df.resample('H').mean() # you can use .sum() also
hourly_mean_df.head()

                          v1          v2         v3
2000-01-01 00:00:00     0.516001    0.461119    0.467895
2000-01-01 01:00:00     0.530603    0.458208    0.550892
2000-01-01 02:00:00     0.472090    0.522278    0.508345
2000-01-01 03:00:00     0.515713    0.486906    0.541538
2000-01-01 04:00:00     0.514543    0.478097    0.489217
```

Now you can plot this hourly summary

```
hourly_mean_df.plot()
```

[image: Hourly Plot]

Comment: I do not want to resample the Data. Just show every hour unter the x-axis. The df is over one week long and plot() showes just the day, not the hours.

Comment: you should make it clear, what you want in the question then

Comment: do you just want to set the tick at every hour?

Comment: Yes, tick at every hour :-)

Comment: looks like a duplicate of this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945971/pandas-timeseries-plot-setting-x-axis-major-and-minor-ticks-and-labels

Comment: no, the question bihind yopur link is not from me, and does not help me

Comment: @kolja it does show how to use custom time units for ticks. take a look properly