# How can I set two-level ticks for Pandas hour/weekday plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a DataFrame which is structurally similar to the following:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
from mpu.datetime import generate  # pip install mpu

mind, maxd = datetime(2018, 1, 1), datetime(2018, 12, 30)
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': [generate(mind, maxd) for _ in range(10)]})
```

I want to understand how this data is distributed over hours of the day and days of the week. I can get them via:

```
df['weekday'] = df['datetime'].dt.weekday
df['hour'] = df['datetime'].dt.hour
```

And finally I have the plot:

```
ax = df.groupby(['weekday', 'hour'])['datetime'].count().plot(kind='line', color='blue')
ax.set_ylabel("#")
ax.set_xlabel("time")
plt.show()
```

which gives me:

[image]

But you can notice that it is hard to distinguish the weekdays and the hours are not even noticeable. How can I get two-level labels similar to the following?

[image]

Comment: Enable grid, set the minorlocator/formatter to hours and the majorlocator/formatter to day? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13674286/8881141

Comment: @Mr.T I can't get that one working. It does not throw an error, but it just looks like the image on top (well, some grid is there - but I don't think it's by weekday and certainly not by hour.

Comment: What about missing days or hours? Are they supposed to be in the chart or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you assume that every possible weekday and hour actually appears in the data, the axis units will simply be hours, with Monday midnight being 0, and Sunday 23h being 24*7-1 = 167.
You can then tick every 24 hours with major ticks and label every noon with the respective day of the week.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator, FuncFormatter, NullFormatter

# Generate example data
N = 5030
delta = (dt.datetime(2019, 1, 1) - dt.datetime(2018, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': np.array("2018-01-01").astype(np.datetime64) + 
                               (delta*np.random.rand(N)).astype(np.timedelta64)})

# Group the data
df['weekday'] = df['datetime'].dt.weekday
df['hour'] = df['datetime'].dt.hour

counts = df.groupby(['weekday', 'hour'])['datetime'].count()

ax = counts.plot(kind='line', color='blue')
ax.set_ylabel("#")
ax.set_xlabel("time")
ax.grid()
# Now we assume that there is data for every hour and day present
assert len(counts) == 7*24
# Hence we can tick the axis with multiples of 24h
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(24))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(1))

days = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]
def tick(x,pos):
    if x % 24 == 12:
        return days[int(x)//24]
    else:
        return ""
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(NullFormatter())
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(FuncFormatter(tick))
ax.tick_params(which="major", axis="x", length=10, width=1.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Do you think it is possible to make the tick at 12:00 a bit thicker? Or at 08:00 and 16:00? And maybe have a minor grid for that?

Comment: I currently don't understand how your solution works. I will look at the documentation of NullFormatter after work and (if it is ok for you) edit your answer a bit with what I think I understand.

Comment: The problem is that matplotlib allows for two levels of ticks only (major and minor), so introducing a third kind of tick is hardly possible. It would require to make a completely new axis, synchronize it with the existing one and then you have two more levels available.

Comment: Ok, so it would be at least another question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly the visualization you mentioned, but an idea would be to unstack your pandas time series and then plot.

```
df.groupby(['weekday', 'hour'])['datetime'].count().unstack(level=0).plot()
```

The result would be the following with the data you provided on your code is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to test it with your dataset, and pandas datetime is sometimes difficult with matplotlib datetime. But the idea is to set [major and minor ticks](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html) and [define their grid qualities](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.grid.html) separately:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import dates as mdates

#create sample data and plot it
from io import StringIO
data = StringIO("""
X,A,B
2018-11-21T12:04:20,1,8
2018-11-21T18:14:17,6,7
2018-11-22T02:18:21,8,14
2018-11-22T12:31:54,7,8
2018-11-22T20:33:20,5,5
2018-11-23T12:23:12,13,2
2018-11-23T21:31:05,7,12
""")
df = pd.read_csv(data, parse_dates = True, index_col = "X")
ax=df.plot()

#format major locator
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
#format minor locator with specific hours
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.HourLocator(byhour = [8, 12, 18]))
#label major ticks
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%a %d %m'))
#label minor ticks
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%H:00"))
#set grid for major ticks
ax.grid(which = "major", axis = "x", linestyle = "-", linewidth = 2)
#set grid for minor ticks with different properties
ax.grid(which = "minor", axis = "x", linestyle = "--", linewidth = 1)

plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]