# Why is the first of the month automatically plotted as tick in matplotlib.plot_date?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a geodataframe with date as string and Date as a datetime64[ns]. I am using matplotlib 3.0.2. I've tried clearing the data using `plt.cla()`, `plt.clear()` and `plt.clf(`) as mentioned in other posts and questions but no matter what, the data plots what seems to be a major and minor axis formatting without any prompting - assuming that in `plot_date` the first of the month is the "major" axis. [This is my graph (edited for clarity)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4YiY.png). It seems caused by new updates in 3.0.2 (from 2.1.0) it's hard to figure out what exactly is causing this

I saw this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945971/pandas-timeseries-plot-setting-x-axis-major-and-minor-ticks-and-labels) which seems to be in the vein of my issue, but in this instance it was desired to be using sub dates, etc, while I am confused since this has not been a consistent issue for me in other similar datasets.

```
Dataframe:
          Date    var_name
106 2018-04-03  0.79132056
216 2018-04-09  0.75112718
546 2018-06-12  0.73359674
646 2018-07-03  0.72600174
706 2018-07-23  0.71263647



figsize=(14,10)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=figsize)
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])

plt.xticks(rotation=30, ha='right')
plt.grid(color='k', lw=0.2)

plt.plot_date(data.Date, data.var_name)
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Jody and ImportanceOfBeingErnest for pointing out this was caused by a change in kwargs in matplotlib version 3.0.2 that is fixed in 3.1 where `interval_multiples=True` is now the default to plot the first of the month in addition to other ticks. @ImportanceOfBeingErnest was a reviewer.

[PR link](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/10841)

most relevant matplotlib issue [#12925](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12925). Matplot lib issue [#9978](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9978) is also relevant

Comment: I don't think those are minor ticks. Could you rotate the labels, such that they become readable?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest sure thing- for some reason `fig.autofmt_xdate()` did not have an effect of rotating the labels which is why this method was used

Comment: That is definitely a problem with the `AutoDateLocator` in use. It ticks the 29th of each month in addition. I fear the only way to circumvent this is to use a `MonthLocator`. You can open [an issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues) about it if you want.

Comment: I wouldn't say it was a bug, but a change so that AutoDateLocator that set the kwarg `interval_multiple=True`.  That kwarg tries to make the first of the month a tick no matter what.  If you set it to False, you should largely get the old behaviour back (you'll have to manually set the locator though).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @TheImportanceOfBeingErnest and @JodyKlymak for their comments to suggest using the `AutoDateLocator` and `MonthLocator`. The following snippet ended up being my workaround. [Final figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZQqQ.png)

*Approach with more control:*

```
figsize=(14,10)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=figsize)
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])

plt.xticks(rotation=30, ha='right')
plt.grid(color='k', lw=0.2)

months = matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(months)
year_month = matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(year_month)

plt.plot_date(data.Date, data.var_name)
```

*Approach still using AutoDateLocator while retaining old behavior*:

```
locator = matplotlib.dates.AutoDateLocator(interval_multiples=False)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
```