# Time Series Analysis from reading a csv file with pandas

Tags: python

I want to create a program to plot graphs for every 3rd column, using 1 and 2 as the date time which is x axis and 3 as the value which is y axis. Can someone help with the code?

[using python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVLKy.png)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow. We don't write code for you. But you can find good examples here. I suggest you search this site for "matplotlib time series" (with matplotlib being a popular graphing library that is used with Python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas timeseries plot setting x-axis major and minor ticks and labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945971/pandas-timeseries-plot-setting-x-axis-major-and-minor-ticks-and-labels)

Comment: Please don't add data/code/error messages as images. Post the text directly here on SO.